Cluster configuration for clickhouse
According to the documentation for the flyway extension configuration (https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/clickhouse-zookeeper-path-233439794.html) we can set the cluster name with configuration properties:
flyway.clickhouse.clusterName=example_cluster
I am using SpringBoot and I see that when I set these properties the extension does not load them correctly:


The only way I've been able to do this is by using the API and manually setting these values. I've tried setting environment variables with no luck. Any ideas to use the properties configuration?
Thanks and best regards

your environment variable means the 1st picture?

Hi @jsc0218 The first image is the springboot configuration for my springboot application
